# Using NDK header when building vendor module with VNDK enabled

Tags: android, android-source, android-build

I have a native vendor module built with AOSP (android 9.0.0_r35).
This module uses `android/input.h` header. Note that this header is included in the android [NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/input).

When enabling the [VNDK](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/vndk/enabling), building module fails with `fatal error: 'android/input.h' file not found` error.

This is caused by android build system (see [compiler.go](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:build/soong/cc/compiler.go;l=300?ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject)) who does not export the `CommonGlobalIncludes` when VNDK is enabled so frameworks/native/include (containing input.h) is not in include list.

I tried adding libandroid to LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES without success.
The [android doc](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/vndk/enabling#managing-headers) mentioning header does not refers to NDK includes.
This file is supposed to stay stable so I think it is safe to use it from a vendor module.

Is there a module (LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES or LOCAL_HEADER_LIBRARIES) to include to allow using NDK headers ?
Else, is it safe to add `$(ANDROID_BUILD_TOP)/out/soong/ndk/sysroot/usr/include/` to include path ?

Test code :
Android.mk :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE:= testIncludeInput_vendor
LOCAL_PROPRIETARY_MODULE := true
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libandroid 
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE:= testIncludeInput_system
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= test.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libandroid 
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

test.cpp :

```
#include <android/input.h>
```