# Add libraries to AOSP and use them in the NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-source

(new to AOSP)

I'm confused about the process of adding assets to AOSP (Android 10+) and using those assets in app development.  For example, say I want to create my own AOSP build and add Boost (or anything) as a library, how then can I use this *via* the NDK when building apps (and share it with my team)?  As opposed to creating a package (AAR or something) of boost, where every consumer would have to download it and build it into the apk/apb.

I suspect that the answer is doing this with the [VNDK](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/vndk#why-vndk), but I still don't see how once I add a `LL-NDK` (I think?) library, how other developers would be able to access this with their NDKs.

Another way to ask the question, if some phone manufacturer, "SamPlusXel" creates their own version of AOSP, adds a bunch of vendor libraries, do they have a custom NDK they're developers can use to create apps to take advantage of all the vendor libraries they add (*via* Android-Studio)?  Or is this just not something they do?  Or can this only be done if they build their app along side AOSP?

(I think this question is similar in nature to [Using NDK header when building vendor module with VNDK enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62390189/1861346))

Comment: I believe the answer to this is that apps are prohibited from accessing any libraries on the system that aren't explicitly inserted into the NDK in the Soong builds.  As such, in my example above, either they have to publish their own NDK, or apps that need system/vendor libs must be included in the AOSP build tree.